# Need help on PHP json_decode()

Tags: php

Need help and advice on `json_decode()` in PHP. I am working on a CURL operation for an API call and the return result is a JSON. What is the syntax that I need to access the field `pgid`?

**CURL Operation**

```
$output = curl_exec($ch);
$rslt = json_decode($output, true);
var_dump($rslt);
```

**The `var_dump()` output**

```
array (size=1)
'protection-groups' => array (size=3)
    0 => array (size=2)
        'ppsDropped' => float 0
        'pgid' => int 13
    1 => array (size=2)
        'ppsDropped' => float 7.9957930115316
        'pgid' => int 18
    2 => array (size=2)
        'ppsDropped' => float 5302.7606884163
        'pgid' => int 19
```

Comment: What you tried show the code

Answer (score 0):

try below code that will loop through and get all `pgid`

```
foreach($rslt['protection-groups'] as $group)
{
   echo $group['pgid'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this :

```
$output = curl_exec($ch);
$rslt = json_decode($output, true);
$idsArray = array();

foreach($rslt['protection-groups'] as $key => $value){
  $pgId = $value['pgid'];
  echo $pgId;
  //Or in case you need all the PGID's in array then :
  array_push($idsArray,$value['pgid']);
}

print_r($idsArray);
exit();
```

Comment: It solve my problem !! Thank you all for the advice.

Comment: Happy to help you ! Please accept my answer.